# Syncing data to server in a background thread: multiple-contexts in core data

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two `NSManagedObjectContext` : parentContext which is the main context and a childContext with `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. 
Using the childContext I am syncing data to the server in a background thread and after the sync succeeds I set `data.isSynced = true`.

The user might change the data during the sync. This will mark the data as dirty by setting `data.isSynced = false`.

Both threads (main and syncing) are running concurrently and a bad scenario can happen here if the parentContext has `data.isSynced == false` and the childContext has `data.isSynced == true`. Calling the `childContext.save()` will override changes in the parentContext and I will miss the changes and won't sync again the updated data to the server.

How can I improve the current design?
Is there a way to customize the merge between the parent and child contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a single bool flag, use 2 dates instead. One date is for the last edit and the other is for the last sync. They are each only ever updated from 1 thread. The background thread will read both to check if data needs to be synced but that's fine.